# Testing an X2 capacitor with a capacimeter. Is it broken?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, test-equipment, units

This came up as a comment in [other question I posted](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/253283/x2-capacitor-alternative-component-or-circuit), but I thought it could be of use for someone else if posted separately.

I have an X2 cap rated ".47K275V~X2". Is that `0.47uF = 470nF`? When I set my capacimeter wheel to the "200n" position and test the cap, it reads "40.2nF".

If I set the wheel to both 2m and 200u the capacimeter reads zero. When I go down to 20u it reads 0.04uF, then with 2u it reads .040uF, and with 200n, it reads 40.2nF. If I step down one more time to 20n, it reads 1.

Is the cap bad? Am I interpreting the rating on the cap case right?

Thanks!

Comment: @JRE I tried with 2m and 200u and it kept showing zero, when I go down to 20u it reads 0.04uF, then with 2u it reads .040uF, and with 200n, it reads 40.2nF. If I step down one more time to 20n, it reads 1.

Comment: I assume it is out of circuit

Comment: @TonyStewart yes, it is out, I've desoldered it.

Comment: Picture please. I would interpret 47K as 47nF.

Comment: @EJP the cap is exactly like the one in TonyStewart answer below, see picture there. Also, AFAIK the letter K stands for "10% tolerance" and not "thousand". However let me know by the picture if you believe this is a 47nF cap and I'm looking it wrong. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be defective and a common problem in Brazil too on coffee makers.[image]  Perhaps line transients are common or the parts were fake Chinese clones and never good to begin with.

However, it should not affect function , unless noise suppression is critical and induces faults.
 This is not a common fault in Canada, but fake parts are common and easy to overlook.

Comment: Yes, precisely! I have also a Phillips coffee maker that went bad because of this. Why do you say it should not affect function? I understand the main function is to suppress noise, but for example in the coffee maker failure, replacement of the X2 cap solves it (for example: http://www.eevblog.com/forum/chat/another-polypropylene-capacitor-failure-senseo/). Could it be that the cap is serving another function in the circuit as well, or that by going bad it affects the circuit negatively?

Comment: possibly...perhaps the water pump uses a diode series on AC line with a spring loaded solenoid and the lower impedance across the line assists the solenoid action. if that does expresso.... https://dicasdozebio.com/2014/01/19/dica-conserto-de-cafeteira-domestica-philips-senseo/ or check with distributor for quality recalls, defective parts used...

Answer (score 0):

The dot before 47 (.47) means 0.470 mikroFarads or 470 nF, K means +-10%
The capacitor lost value and may be cannot work in circuit.